# Python Nested Loop For Sequence of Several Rowes

Tags: python, loops, nested

How do i use a loop nested within a loop to create this output:

```
100
101 102
103 104 105
106 107 108 109
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using a while loop with certain other variables:

```
>>> st, end, length = 100, 110, 1
>>> while st < end:
...     print (" ".join(map(lambda x: "%3d" % x, range(st,st+length))))
...     st += length
...     length += 1
... 
100
101 102
103 104 105
106 107 108 109
```

Note that I have used a lambda instead of `str` in the map, this is so that different width numbers don't break up the indentation.

You can similarly base this on the width of the final line as below (in which case there is no need to keep track of the end variable I was doing above):

```
>>> st, width = 1, 1
>>> while width <= 15:
...     print (" ".join(map(lambda x: "%3d" % x, range(st, st + width))))
...     st += width
...     width += 1
... 
  1
  2   3
  4   5   6
  7   8   9  10
 11  12  13  14  15
 16  17  18  19  20  21
 22  23  24  25  26  27  28
 29  30  31  32  33  34  35  36
 37  38  39  40  41  42  43  44  45
 46  47  48  49  50  51  52  53  54  55
 56  57  58  59  60  61  62  63  64  65  66
 67  68  69  70  71  72  73  74  75  76  77  78
 79  80  81  82  83  84  85  86  87  88  89  90  91
 92  93  94  95  96  97  98  99 100 101 102 103 104 105
106 107 108 109 110 111 112 113 114 115 116 117 118 119 120
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use two-level for loop:

```
x = 100
for i in range(1, 5):
    for j in range(i):
        print(x, end=" ")
        x += 1
    print("")
```

Comment: When I put this code in it isn't working, can you try showing me again?

Comment: Works for me, did you copy&paste correctly? If you are on Python3 you'll need to adapt the `print` calls.

Comment: It says invalid invalid syntax. Do you mean to enter it like this like python 3?

Comment: @NewAtThis I've updated my answer. In fact, `print x,` is a short hand for "print x followed by a space with out newline" in python 2.x. But the print function in python3 is much harder to use...

Answer (score 0):

Something like this???

```
start = 100
lines = 5
for i in range(lines):
    stop = start + i + 1
    for j in range(a, stop):
        print j,
    start = stop
    print
```